# How do I only use bootstrap progress bar without Bootstrap CSS styles taking over my site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My site has its own custom CSS code and doesn't use any bootstrap. But I have a table in my Django project that I want to make a percentage bar using only the [bootstrap progress bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/) via the [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-progressbar/0.8.5) and nothing else from bootstrap.

So I added this below the jquery script tag in the header of my base.html like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-progressbar/0.8.5/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js" integrity="sha512-ShSScKTSdSD7IiMKfgTdqaEY8gOGm5cNfqMr6Wc5BZvMgc1UveS+UqpS0TNUtRD1CZ9KhmbGtzwUN7HJlXxY8Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

However, when I place the bootstrap progress bar code in a column  of my table I get no progress bar showing (no change):

```
<td>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">value</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

The progress bar only shows when I add the bootstrap link tag in the header of my base.html like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-progressbar/0.8.5/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js" integrity="sha512-ShSScKTSdSD7IiMKfgTdqaEY8gOGm5cNfqMr6Wc5BZvMgc1UveS+UqpS0TNUtRD1CZ9KhmbGtzwUN7HJlXxY8Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

But the problem is adding that link tag changes the whole CSS of my site along with the desired results of just the progress bar.

How can I only use the bootstrap progress bar for my table without the whole CSS of my site being changed by bootstrap?

Comment: You’re bringing in an entire CSS framework just to apply the styles for a progress bar.. This is very bad design and very inefficient. I would find out what styles you need from the Bootstrap framework (by browsing through the style pages), and just add them to your own project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to import styling without using unwanted css is to open developer tool in a browser, select the element and look into **Computed** tab. You'll see all needed properties - so you can copy it into your own css.